# Reset the Sheikah Scanner+ Target

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

If you go to the Hateno village lab early. You will find out about the upgrades to your Sheikah slate's functions.

You can upgrade your scanner to scan for other things than Shrines by proximity.

I used the feature to scan for some nearly worthless weapon (rusty broadsword). I scanned for other things earlier but I used this one to not make it ping everywhere like it would have with Hylian Mushroom.

I don't see a way to "clear" the targeted item from scanner+ so it can scan only for shrines.

Is there a way to clear your scanner+ targeted item?

To be clear I am NOT asking to turn off the indicator only change it back to search only for shrine and nothing else. Which is not a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same as with the initial shrine alert:

Open the map and press Y to open the scanner menu. There's now a third option to pick some library target. Just disable it once again.

Comment: Thank you. Seems so obvious now.